# Playing audio file directly from a huggingface API

Tags: python, audio, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech

I have a simple program that make a post request from a huggingface model. It saves the audio file. But I want it to play directly instead

```
import requests

API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/espnet/kan-bayashi_ljspeech_vits"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer "}

def query(payload):
    payloads = {
        "inputs": payload,
    }
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payloads)
    with open('main.wav', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)

query("That is very sad to hear")
```

I've tried using the pydub and I get and error as

```
 audio = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(output), format="wav")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/anonymous/envs/langchain/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 773, in from_file
    raise CouldntDecodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.1.1 (GCC) 20230429
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
[wav @ 0x55aa2f3222c0] invalid start code fLaC in RIFF header
[cache @ 0x55aa2f322b40] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:1
cache:pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```